# How do I return my own struct in c++?

Tags: c++, function, struct, return, visual-studio-2017

I'm having trouble creating a function that returns my own struct.

Header:

```
    #ifndef FOOD_H
    #define FOOD_H
    #include <string>

    class Food
    {
    public:
        Food();
        ~Food();
    public:
        struct Fruit {
            std::string name;

        };
        struct Person {
            Fruit favorite;
            Fruit setFavorite(Fruit newFav);
        };

    public:
        Fruit apple;
        Fruit banana;

        Person Fred;
    };
    #endif
```

CPP:

```
    #include "Food.h"

    Food::Food()
    {
    }

    Food::~Food()
    {
    }

    Fruit Food::Person::setFavorite(Fruit newFav)
    {
        return newFav;
    }
```

Main:

```
    #include "Food.h"
    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        Food fd;    
        fd.Fred.favorite = fd.Fred.setFavorite(fd.apple);
        std::cout << fd.Fred.favorite.name;
        system("pause");
    }
```

My errors are:

> E0020 identifier "Fruit" is undefined Food.cpp 11
>
> E0147 declaration is incompatible with "Food::Fruit Food::Person::setFavorite(Food::Fruit newFav)" (declared at line 17 of Food.h) Food.cpp 11

How do I fix these and is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: The error message speaks for itself: `Fruit` => `Food::Fruit`

Comment: I don't know what it's telling me is incompatible with what or how to fix it.

Comment: Compare your code with the declaration in the error message. This is what the compiler expects.

Comment: Okay got it. I wasn't sure how to read the error. Thank you so much.

Comment: `fd.Fred.favorite = fd.Fred.setFavorite(fd.apple);` is a bit weird. `setFavorite` does not do what one would expect from a setter function: It doesn't set `Food::Person::favorite`. I would expect `fd.Fred.setFavorite(fd.apple);` to `favorite  = newFav;` and return nothing.

Comment: Not to mention the member `Person Fred` inside `Food`.

Comment: Yeah, I made this simple example quickly. The actually issue was in a larger project

Comment: True. While there is a case for people to be food, in this case it looks like `Person` should be independent of `Food`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> identifier "Fruit" is undefined
> ```

This error says that there is no definition for `Fruit`.

You have defined a class `Fruit` that is nested within `Food`. Therefore the fully qualified name of the class is `Food::Fruit` as can be seen from the other error message:

> ```
> declaration is incompatible with "Food::Fruit Food::Person::setFavorite(Food::Fruit newFav)"
>                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This error message tells you that the declaration `Food::Person::setFavorite(Fruit newFav)` is incompatible because that function is supposed to return `Food::Fruit` rather than `Fruit` (which is something that doesn't have definition).

---

`Fruit` can be used to refer to `Food::Fruit` within the context of the class `Food`. The definition of this function is outside of the class, so it is not within the context. It is not until the name of the function (`Food::Person::setFavorite`) that the context is established. You could use a trailing return type to avoid using the fully qualified type:

```
auto Food::Person::setFavorite(Fruit newFav) -> Fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, OP's class design could also be improved in my opinion. It seems that OP wants to create a fruit class which should have a is-a relationship with food class. Making it a member of food class doesn't seem right to me. Same thing applies to Person class which should be a separated class instead of being a member of food.

```
#include <string>

class Food
{
    std::string m_name;
        // other stuffs...
};

class Fruit : public Food
{
    // unique fruit members and functions...
};

class Person
{
    Fruit m_favorite;

public:
    void SetFavorite(Fruit favorite);
};

void Person::SetFavorite(Fruit favorite)
{
    m_favorite = favorite;
}

int main()
{
    Fruit apple;
    Person fred;
    fred.SetFavorite(apple);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Semi-related: No violations here, but be careful with proceeding underscores as they can mean something. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). If you never use a preceding underscore you don't have to care when it's legal or not.

Comment: Is it ok to use succeeding underscore to indicate a member?

Comment: You are fine. A single preceding underscore inside a class (or anywhere but the global namespace) is safe. Take it outside the class and you are tempting fate. Take a read of the link in my first comment. It covers all of the rules.